# Passing on a filled array onto a public variable so it can be used in other classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, user-interface

So I've been working on a GUI that has the basic layout completed.  I have the logic all mapped out but the issue I am having is figuring out how to set a filled array to a public variable with all of the String and ints placed in it remaining intact, and not having it kept blank.  By no means am I a pro with programming so please be patient if the answer is very obvious.  I will post the window that I am trying to get the filled array in a public variable.

the public array 'robbieArray' works soley in the main to output any values from it, but past that I cannot use it in frame.  I would just like a solution so that I can access it in frame and other classes I decide to make.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.beans.*;



public class PlayerShow extends JFrame
{

public JFrame playerShowFrame;

public final int CLASSSIZE1 = 2;//subject to change

 //PlayerInput player = new PlayerInput();

public PlayerInput [] robbieArray = new PlayerInput [CLASSSIZE1];



public void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
{
  //    PlayerInput player = new PlayerInput();
Scanner inputRobbieChamps = new Scanner (new FileReader("robbie_mccarthy_champs.txt"));

for (int x = 0; x<CLASSSIZE1;x++)
{
    String champName = inputRobbieChamps.next();
    String role = inputRobbieChamps.next();
    int tier = inputRobbieChamps.nextInt();

    robbieArray[x] = new PlayerInput (champName, role, tier);
System.out.println("The champ name is " + robbieArray[x].getChampName() +     "with a role of " + robbieArray[x].getRole() + " and a tier value of " + robbieArray[x].getTier());   
}
//  PlayerInput [] robbieArray = new PlayerInput[CLASSSIZE1]; 



/*  for (int x = 0; x<CLASSSIZE1; x++)
    {
        robbieArray [x] = new PlayerInput();
    }

    for (int x = 0; x<CLASSSIZE1; x++)
    {
        robbieArray[x].setChampName(inputRobbieChamps.next());
        robbieArray[x].setRole(inputRobbieChamps.next());
        robbieArray[x].setTier(inputRobbieChamps.nextInt());
    }*/
    inputRobbieChamps.close();


}


public PlayerShow ()
{
    frame();
    playerShowFrame.setVisible(false);
}

public void frame()
{
    playerShowFrame = new JFrame();
    playerShowFrame.setVisible(true);
    //playerShowFrame.setSize(900,600);
    playerShowFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getPlayerShowFrame().setBounds(100, 300, 900, 600);
    playerShowFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,8));

    JLabel titleL = new JLabel ("Robbie McCarthy's data:", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    JLabel blank1L = new JLabel (" ", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    JLabel blank2L = new JLabel (" ", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    JLabel champNameL = new JLabel("Champion Name", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    JLabel roleL = new JLabel ("Role", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    JLabel tierL = new JLabel ("Tier", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    JTextArea hugeTF = new JTextArea ();

    hugeTF.setColumns(6);
    hugeTF.setRows(3);

//      for (int x = 0; x<CLASSSIZE1; x++)
//      {
    System.out.println(robbieArray[0].getRole()); // This is where I am checking to see if i get a filled public array

//      }

    hugeTF.setEditable(false);  

    playerShowFrame = getPlayerShowFrame();

    playerShowFrame.add(titleL);

    playerShowFrame.add(blank1L);

    playerShowFrame.add(blank2L);

    playerShowFrame.add(champNameL);

    playerShowFrame.add(roleL);

    playerShowFrame.add(tierL);

    playerShowFrame.add(hugeTF);

}




public JFrame getPlayerShowFrame() {
    return playerShowFrame;
}

public void setPlayerShowFrame(JFrame playerShowFrame) {
        this.playerShowFrame = playerShowFrame;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make array as private static  .. for the sake of encapsulation of OOP, create a static getter

```
private static PlayerInput [] robbieArray = new PlayerInput [CLASSSIZE1];

public static PlayerInput [] getRobbieArray(){
return robbieArray;
}
```

then you can access it by PlayerShow.getRobbieArray()

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to declare it as a static.

```
public static PlayerInput [] robbieArray = new PlayerInput [CLASSSIZE1];
```

Then you can access it from anywhere as `PlayerShow.robbieArray`.

That's assuming you only ever want to have one instance of `PlayerShow` and `robbieArray`.

Otherwise you could pass it to any classes that need to access it as a parameter in their constructor, or via a setter method.

Comment: So in otherwords if i declare robbieArray as public static above my main, and then fill it and set stuff within it in my main.  When i go to access it lets say within frame it I should be able to say something like System.out.println(robbieArray[0].getRole()); and no runtime errors will occur? *Just tried it and the static changed nothing. Umm what a settler method?

Comment: I dont think its proper to put a member as static if thats is not necessary .. it should be static as getter ( method ) to be read-only .. being static member means that it can be access and edited by anything ..

Comment: @user2445983 You need to prefix it with the class name as I showed in my answer - `System.out.println(PlayerShow.robbieArray[0].getRole());`.